# Importing and saving .csv files as variables with the original filebasenames

Tags: import, map

I have a modest number of .csv files that I want to import into mathematica. I would like to save their contents as their filebasename for use throughout my notebook, but I am running into errors as shown below. The .csv files have dimensions of 64x3 and have filenames:

```
{"G1BCM.csv", "G1EXP.csv", "G1FIM.csv", "G1IAM.csv"}
```

Here is my attempt:

```
files = FileNames["*.csv", NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import[#] & /@ files;

filenames = {};
Do[AppendTo[filenames, FileBaseName[files[[i]]]], {i, Length[files]}];

MapThread[Set, {filenames, data}]
```

I have seen `MapThread` used in this way before, but here it yields a string of errors:

```
Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object G1BCM. >>
Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object G1EXP. >>
Set::setraw: Cannot assign to raw object G1FIM. >>
General::stop: Further output of Set::setraw will be suppressed during this calculation. >>

{data} (*which I am not going to bother copying*)
```

This code successfully pulls the data from each of the .csv files and successfully pulls the filebasenames, such that:

```
In[158]:= filenames

Out[158]= {"G1BCM", "G1EXP", "G1FIM", "G1IAM"}
```

This seems like it should set up the MapThread function appropriately. What have I done wrong?

At the end of the day, I want to automate G1BCM=data[[1]], G1EXP=data[[2]], etc. With G1BCM automatically pulled from G1BCM.csv and data[[1]]=the contents of G1BCM.csv.

I have also tried things like:

```
Do[filenames[[i]] := data[[i, All, All]], {i, Length[files]}]
```

But, of course, this just rewrites the elements of the filenames list, and I do not know how to treat elements of a list as variables other than through the MapThread function.

Comment: Your `MapThread` command is trying to assign a value to a string. Try changing it to `MapThread[Set, {ToExpression /@ filenames, data}]`

Comment: `Symbol/@` may work as well.

Comment: @mfvonh That worked! Thank you very much!

Comment: note `Set` threads on its own so you don't need `MapThread` : `Set @@ {Symbol /@ filenames, data}`

Comment: could you please update the title of your question to something which makes sense?

Comment: @chris Sorry about that. I am not sure why I missed it. It is fixed now.

Comment: @george2079 That is more elegant. I will update my answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many thanks to @mfvonh for this answer (posted as a comment below my question).

The issue was that I was trying to assign values to strings. using `ToExpression` to convert the strings to expressions worked beautifully. My final code is as follows:

```
files = FileNames["*.csv", NotebookDirectory[]];
data = Import[#] & /@ files;

filenames = {};
Do[AppendTo[filenames, FileBaseName[files[[i]]]], {i, Length[files]}];

MapThread[Set, {ToExpression /@ filenames, data}]
```

This does exactly what I wanted. Thank you all for your help!

---

**EDIT:**

As @george2079 mentioned, `Set` threads on its own so `MapThread` is unneeded. A more elegant line would then be the following (replacing `MapThread`):

```
Set @@ {Symbol /@ filenames, data}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is a different approach (for the solution of your problem see @mfvonh solution). What I would probably do in your case would be to create one "database" containing all your data.

Let's say you have your file names:

```
files = {"G1BCM.csv", "G1EXP.csv", "G1FIM.csv", "G1IAM.csv"};
```

then you can create a database as simply as:
***(In your case, just replace here below `foo` with `Import`)***

```
db = Association[Map[Rule[FileBaseName[#], foo[#]] &, files]]
```

> `<|G1BCM->foo[G1BCM.csv],G1EXP->foo[G1EXP.csv],G1FIM->foo[G1FIM.csv],G1IAM->foo[G1IAM.csv]|>`

Then, for example to get the "data" (values) corresponding to "G1BCM" (key) just type:

```
db["G1BCM"]
```

> `foo["G1BCM.csv"]`

(in your case, `foo[...]` will be replaced with real data)

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So, this worked, but with the structure of the rest of my code, it is a bit more convenient to have each saved as a separate variable. I will keep this structure in mind in the future though. I have not yet worked with associations much as I just recently upgraded to V10.2.

Comment: @Snipatomic You're welcome !

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have V.10 Associations are out otherwise @SquareOne's solution is the better choice. Anyway quick and dirty solution I've used in the past is:

```
filenames = {"a", "b", "c", "d"};
data = {12, 20, 40, 60};
d = MapThread[Rule, {filenames, data}];
```

Then accessing data for a particular name is done with

```
  "a"/.d
```

Obviously, replace `filenames` and `data`. But it looks like you have that part covered.

Comment: This is exactly what I was trying to do, but as @mfvonh mentioned, I was mistakenly trying to assign values to strings.